# PHP regex street address

Tags: php, regex

I need to write a regex statement for street addresses.  It's for a class so it doesn't have to be too fancy.  Basically, I want it to accept a) a group of numbers, b) a space, c) a street name, either starting with a letter or number, and d) anything after that.

So far, this is what I have:

```
^\d+\s[0-9a-zA-Z]*
```

I'm using the example 123 Sesame Street.  It accepts 123 Sesame, but doesn't match Street, or, in other words, d) anything after that.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this. I guarantee it will cause more trouble than it's worth. This will already fail for 123a Sesame Street, or O'Leary Street (Christchurch NZ), or Ha-Ha Road (Woolwich, London), and doubtless many others I haven't found. You haven't explained why you think you need to do this, but whatever the reason, find a better way.

Comment: I have to do it because it's for homework and it's part of an assignment.  It doesn't have to be great; he just wants us to demonstrate a basic understanding of regex.

Comment: And you will be demonstrating that basic understanding by asking here?

Comment: He also told us to search the internet for ideas on how to write the statements.  There are multiple fields we have to write the statements for.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a space in street character list.

```
^\d+\s[0-9a-zA-Z ]* // or \s instead of space
                ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed you won’t learn anything by having someone give you the answer.. this guide is really fantastic:

[https://www.princeton.edu/\~mlovett/reference/Regular-Expressions.pdf](https://www.princeton.edu/%5C%7Emlovett/reference/Regular-Expressions.pdf)

But, With that said.. in its simplest form to accomplish your goal:

^[0-9]+\s.*$

But what if you lived at 147B N. Henderson Way? This wouldn’t match your criteria.

Comment: He told us to search online for ideas.  There were multiple fields to write statements for.

Your link doesn't work.  Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up going with '^\d+\s.*'

Comment: the ~ tilde in the link does not work right for some reason in my link.. manually add it instead of the "%5C%7" HTML code that it turns it into. Good to have...